# Cloud Firestore: Add Field Value To Document

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I want to create a field value called *question_count* and I want to increment that value and add it to my cloud Firestore document. I've already tried:

```
document_reference.update("question_count", FieldValue.increment(1))
```

**The problem**: I have to manually add the *question_count* field to my cloud Firestore document and then the above code will increment that value.
[Cloud Firestore Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvImr.png)
**What I want**: I was told that using DocumentReference *update(...)* with the field value specified would create the field value if it was not already created in the cloud Firestore. Was that an incorrect assumption?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `update` method only works when the document already exists. If you want to perform a write that *either* creates the document *or* updates it when it already exists, use `docRef.set(..., SetOptions.merge())`.

So in your case, something like:

```
// Update one field, creating the document if it does not already exist.
Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
data.put("question_count", FieldValue.increment(1));

document_reference.set(data, SetOptions.merge());
```

Also see the documentation on [writing data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update-data).

Comment: Follow up: I understand why it didn't work the first time I created the document. But the update method still wasn't working after the document was created... your thoughts on this?

Comment: That sounds not happen: once the document exists, update should work. Let me know if you can reproduce that problem.